# Compare-Object with variables containing different properties

Tags: powershell, properties, compare

I'm in the middle of writing a script that finds inconsistensis  of the servers in our infrastructure. Basicly what i do is source the Name and status of our servers from 2 different sources and find missmatches. Source 1 is our SQL with the properties Name and Status (status can be either InUse or Removed) Source 2 is from vCenter with properties Name and PowerState (PoweredOn or PoweredOff) These are then stored in different variables,

Using this info i'd like to compare Status and PowerState of each server, InUse and PoweredOn should match and be outputted to null while all others (for ex InUse and PoweredOff) should not match and be outputted to a table or csv along with the servername for further investigation.

I tried renaming the properties to the same name and then filtering them with ForEach but i can´t quite get it to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions:**

- You're using PowerShell
- I'm assuming that you know how to fetch the lists into a dictionary. For sake of ease, I'll assume you're using hashtables.
- I'm assuming that the names of the servers are *exactly* the same in both sources. If not, you will need to account for this in your script (lookup table perhaps) or adjust the names in one source.

$sqllist is the list from SQL, keyed by name
$vclist is the list from vCenter, keyed by Name

```
$output = @()
foreach ($serversql in $sqllist)
{
  $entry = $null
  $servervc = $vclist.Get($serversql.Name)
  if ($serversql.Status -match 'InUse' `
    -and $servervc.PowerState -match 'PoweredOn')
  {
    $entry = [PsCustomObject]@{
      Name=$serversql.Name
      SqlStatus=$null
      vCenterStatus=$null
    }
  } else
  {
    $entry = [PsCustomObject]@{
      Name=$serversql.Name
      SqlStatus=$serversql.Status
      vCenterStatus=$servervc.PowerState
    }
  }
}
$output | Export-CSV -Path log.csv
```